# Take tag value and do an arithmetic operation with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-selectors

This can be sound ridiculous, but i really want to know if this is possible, and how to make it.
This is my first time in StackOverflow about asking, because i learn here how to code with style, sure with the questions of people like me. Thanks for make me feel like if Stackoverflow is were my house.

Let's ask.

I'm making a php script, more faster than Donald Trump begun to hate the Oreo's cookies.

The script prints this as code **HTML**

```
<strong>$</strong><h1>1800</h1>USD
<strong>$</strong><h1>800</h1>USD
```

So, this is when the mad situation comes...
Whit Jquery i want to take the both h1 elements and i want to make aritmetic operations whit them. I can do this with php and mysql, i know. But about time, i prefer to do this with jQuery.

¿Is there anybody to can help me?
Crazy and very very simple example:

**H1 + H1** OR **H1 - H1** = **NUMBER RESULT OF THE OPERATION.**

Comment: Do you want to get summation of all h1 elements?

Comment: You mean something like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/7jxr867q/1/) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to get the summation, you can use this code :

```js
var total = 0;
$("h1").each(function(index, item) {
  total += Number($(item).text());
});
alert(total);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<strong>$</strong><h1>1800</h1>USD
<strong>$</strong><h1>800</h1>USD
```

Comment: Your answer help me a lot of. Thank you :D

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery `.each(function(){})` to iterate and find out text in each of `h1` tag.For demo I put them inside an array and can apply any mathematical operation

```
var a=[];
$('h1').each(function(){
   var tempText = $(this).text().trim(); // Remove white space
   console.log(tempText)
   a.push(tempText)
})
```

**Edit**
Use parseInt to convert it to integer

```
`var tempText = parseInt($(this).text().trim());` // Converts to integer
```

So `a` will be now an array of integers

[Example](https://jsfiddle.net/nc1m603z/)

Answer (score 0):

Hello you can do it like this

```
var sum = 0;
$('h1').each(function(k,v){
    sum += parseInt($(v).text())
})
console.log(sum)
```

Comment: That was fine, Thank you :D

Answer (score 0):

Crazy and very simple:

```
  $("strong")
     .next("h1")
     .get()
     .map(function(el){
       return $(el).text();
     })
     .reduce(function(a,b){
       return parseInt(a)+parseInt(b);
     })
```

[ https://jsfiddle.net/hLwxrpoq/ ]

Comment: Thanks for answer me

Answer (score 0):

Try using `.eq()` to cache `h1` elements , `.html()` to return results; `+` operator to cast text to `Number`

```js
// select all `h1` elements
var h = $("h1");
// results
var result = $("#result");
// first `h1`
var first = h.eq(0).text();
var second = h.eq(1).text();

result.html(function() {
  var add = +first + +second;
  var subtract = +first - +second;
  return "Add first `h1` to second `h1`:" + add 
  + "<br>Substract second `h1` from first `h1`:" + subtract
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<strong>$</strong><h1>1800</h1>USD<br>
<strong>$</strong><h1>800</h1>USD<br>
<br>
<div id="result"></div>
```

Comment: And this is fine and helpful too :D

Comment: this was helpful too :D

Answer (score 0):

You retrieve the inner text of the HTML by using `.text()` and parse it as an integer using `parseInt` as the others above have explained.

You can then append it to your HTML after that.

Your HTML might look like this:

```
<div id="math">
  <h1>800</h1>
  <h1>1800</h1>
</div>
<h1 id="answer"></h1>
```

And your jquery like this:

```
var math = $("#math"); //Get the math element
var numbers = math.find('h1'); //Get all the numbers from the math div
var answer = $("#answer"); //Get the element
var total = 0;

numbers.each( function() {
    total += parseInt( $(this).text() ); // Add each number together
});

answer.append( total ); // Append the total to the answer element
```

Here is a fiddle.

https://jsfiddle.net/75qxy57d/1/